# EF Persisting Columns Ignore those that are not in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have mvc view that has some columns from entity. When I do db.SaveChanges(), all columns that are not part of the view are being updated with NULL, so overwriting any values that were present in database record. That's very lame.
I am aware that I could do ModelView for the the view and bind just those columns that i want. But I am looking for a way to simply tell EF, to 'ignore' columns during this particular update, to NOT update columns that are NOT present in the MvC View.
I am using EF 5. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show the code that transfers the view data to the entity in the context?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to avoid creating a separate Model but i guess you know what you are doing so maybe try this approach to trick EF into thinking the properties have not changed:

```
var entry = context.Entry(obj);
entry.Property(name).IsModified = false;
```

I haven't tried it myself but it should be possible in EF 5. If it doesn't work try accessing the property entry by searching the `entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames` collection and then setting the `IsModified` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what i needed is this

```
User u = db.Users.Find(user.UserID);
        if (u!=null) {

            TryUpdateModel(u);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
                db.SaveChanges();
}
```